# Simple name generator in C#

Tags: c#, generator

I need some help with completing this simple name "generator"
We've just started programming in high school, so I would like a simpler solution. This is all I've got for now, but the output in the textbox is `System.String[]`

```
private void Btn_gen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  textbox.Text = textbox.Text + name((int) count.Value) + Environment.NewLine;
}

private string name(int count)
{
  string heslo = "";
  string[] names = new string[] {"Abby", "Uther", "Thomas", "Michelle", "Abraham", "Bendy"};
  string[] surnames = {"The Mighty", "The Clumsy", "The Strong", "The Lightbringer", "The Pyromancer", "The Necromancer"};
  Random gnč = new Random();
  for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
  {
    int nč = gnč.Next(0, names.Length);
    heslo = heslo + names;
  }
  return heslo;
}
```

Comment: Replace the last statement within the loop with --> heslo = heslo + names[nč]; , also if you want to impress your teacher change the "heslo"string to StringBuilder and use append. Better for performance when "count" is more than say 3-4

Comment: What is the issue? This question is appropriate for Stackoverflow if it has a bug and you don't know how to fix it. If your code works but you just want a review, try posting on [CodeReview StackExchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you aren't appending a random name, but rather the type name `System.String[]`, which is the formal type name of your `names` variable, to your string.

Change `heslo = heslo + names` to

```
heslo = heslo + names[nč];
```

This will take a random element out of the names array.